# Error while importing my Kapsel cordova project in eclipse on org.apache.cordova.whitelist

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, smp

Kapsel Cordova project for Android as a Platform

Hello, I am very new to Kapsel Cordova and to SMP3.0 .I have created the Kapsel Cordova project using the command line Interface(CLI) for platform as an android .I have also added different plugins related to the cordova which I want in my app to work like camera and the geolocation.

```
The ISSUE:while I have created the Kapsel Cordova project and prepared it using CLI and importing the project into the Eclipse IDE .       WhiteList.png
```

I am  getting the above error in my project.While importing the project as an already existing project of Android in eclipse Juno.

```
So,can you please help me out for explaining what exactly the Whitelisting is and what are its methods and all since I feel the documentation is not sufficient to answer my  question.
```

> IDE:Eclipse Juno
>
> Android device 4.0.0
>
> JDK 1.7
>
> JRE 1.7

Please Help....!!!
Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to get the Kapsel Cordova logon page in android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840455/unable-to-get-the-kapsel-cordova-logon-page-in-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Try this for windows (uninstall you cordova version)
```

**npm uninstall -g cordova**

```
 2. Try this for MAC
```

**sudo npm uninstall -g cordova**

### And You Can Also Added Cordova Previous Versions Like This

```
3. Install Cordova Previous Versions As bellow command.
```

Cordova is installed using the Node Package Manager (npm). Type the following in the command window to install:

**npm install -g cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13**  // its command tyr this if any confusion farther steps then tell me

Enjoy ...!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help Kaushal. It worked fine for the version 3.6.3-0.2.13.but not for the version 5.0.0 version(Latest)

Comment: yes its not latest version but it will work fine. and right now all cordova developer facing problem latest version like whiteline pugging.

Comment: If you want the  version 5.0.0 version(Latest) cordova then please update your SDK Api Level 22 . its work latest cordova version.

Comment: Yes my Android SDK is the upgraded one..:)